# Select Distinct from Object Array

Tags: knockout.js

In KO is it possible to return a Distinct list from an object array based on a property in the array.

I have a 'Dialog' array that has a collection of objects, one of the properties in the object is call 'photo'. I want to just pull distinct Photos from the array.

My code so far:

```
  my.vm.uniquePhotos = ko.computed(function () {
  return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(my.vm.Dialog());
}, my.vm);
```

The code above is returning all the 'Photos' in the array, but I just want distinct photos.

```
    <div id="participants" data-bind='foreach: uniquePhotos'>

       <img data-bind="attr: { src: photo }" />  

   </div>
```

Regards
Melt

Comment: Hi Damien,I don't want any objects just the unique names of the 'photos' that exist within the array  -- so at the the end of a piece of Dialog I can display the unique 'photos' of the people involved in the Dialog -- hope I explained that OK - Thanks - Melt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get an array that contains only unique photo, you could that :

```
my.vm.uniquePhotos = ko.computed(function () {

    var photos = my.vm.Dialog();
    var o = {};
    var r = [];   

    for(var i=0; i<photos.length;i++)
       o[photos[i].photo] = photos[i].photo;

    for(i in o)
       r.push(o[i]);
}, my.vm);
```

Or if the photo property is the only info you need in the object, you could use arrayMap, to get an array that contains the urls and them use arrayGetDistinctValues.

```
my.vm.uniquePhotosUrl = ko.computed(function () { 
   return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(
       ko.utils.arrayMap(my.vm.Dialog(), function(p){
          return p.photo;
       })
   );   
}, my.vm);
```

The view :

```
<div id="participants" data-bind='foreach: uniquePhotosUrl '>
    <img data-bind="attr: { src: $data}" />  
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Damien, the photo property value is the only info I need - using the arrayMap code I'm getting an error -'p is not defined' - Regards,Melt

Comment: Sorry, now it's fixed.